# Adding 'Authorization' header causes Spring Security to secure a permitted endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, spring-security, basic-authentication

So, I have this in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
public class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // Use this configuration for endpoints starting with 'api'
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                // Do not secure endpoints receiving callbacks
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(""/api/v1/notification").permitAll()
                // Allow only users with role "ROLE_API"
                .anyRequest().hasRole(Users.UserRoles.ROLE_API.role.replace("ROLE_", ""))
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                // Do not create any sessions
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // Disable csrf
                .csrf().disable();            

    }
```

}

which should not secure `/api/v1/notification`. If I call that endpoint without `Authorization: Basic abcd` in the `HTTP` header the request is permitted, but if I add the `Authorization: Basic abcd` header, I get a `401` http response code.

NB: `Basic abcd` is just random so no such user is in my database

The question is why adding `Authorization...` in the http header makes the endpoint secured again?

Comment: Does `/api/v1/notification` behave differently with a user in context or the same either way?

Comment: It still acts as a secured endpoint.provided the http header `Authorization` is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, this can be kind of confusing since it means that a legitimate client, just with a bad password, could be denied a page that the rest of the world can see without credentials.

Actually, it's by design. Generally speaking, an authorization system would need to know who the user is before knowing whether the user can do X, Y, or Z operation. And even with a public endpoint, it's possible that the endpoint may behave differently when a user is in context. So, really, they are separate systems with authentication coming first: If a request presents credentials, then the framework will try and authenticate the user and accept or deny the request accordingly.

### An option

I realize you didn't ask for how to address it (you may be completely satisfied with the behavior and just curious), but one thing you can do with `BasicAuthenticationFilter` is configure it to ignore failures, just for that endpoint:

```
static class IgnoreFailuresBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final BasicAuthenticationFilter everythingElse;

    public IgnoreFailuresBasicAuthenticationFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter everythingElse) {
        super(everythingElse.getAuthenticationManager());
        this.everythingElse = everythingElse;
    }

    protected void doFilterInternal(request, response, chain) {
        if ("/api/v1/notification".equals(request.getPathInfo())) {
            super.doFilterInternal(request, response, chain);
        } else {
            this.everythingElse.doFilterInternal(request, response, chain);
        }
    }
}
```

And then replace the filter in the DSL:

```
http
    .httpBasic()
        .withObjectPostProcessor(
            new ObjectPostProcessor<BasicAuthenticationFilter>() {
                public BasicAuthenticationFilter postProcess(BasicAuthenticationFilter filter) {
                    return new IgnoreFailuresBasicAuthenticationFilter(filter);
                }
            });
```

What this will do is allow the filter chain to continue, even though Basic authentication failed. The consequence would be that, in the case authentication fails, you'd get a 403 instead of a 401.

Comment: I had forgotten to ask how to address it (face palm). Well explained. Thanks.

Comment: both `everythingElse.getAuthenticationManager()` and `.doFilterInternal` have `protected` access in `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. How can I bypass that?

Comment: Actually, I've found a solution: 
1. Instead of passing a `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, I am passing an `AuthenticationManager`
2. In the `if` part I am calling `chan.doFilter(request, response)`
3. The `else` part I call `super.doFilterInternal(request, response, chain)`