# How to by pass Authorizatoin header for non secured endpoints in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am using spring webflux and security. I have 3 services A, B, C and two endpoints in service C as below

1. health - secured
2. status - shouldn't be secured

below is my webflux configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecureConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("john")
            .password("{noop}" + "password")
            .roles("")
            .build();
    return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/test/health")
            .authenticated()
            .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Below scenarios are working

1. `health` endpoint with valid `Authorization` header
2. `status` endpoint without `Authorization` header
3. `status` endpoint with valid `Authorization` header

But when i access `status` endpoint with invalid `Authorization` header it's failing with `Anuauthorized`

How to avoid this? because the status call will be originated from Service A, there is different auth required for Service A to Service B which is being passed to Service C because of that it's failing but for Service B to Service C no need any auth for `status` endpoint.

I know we can do by create a fresh request without auth header but i want to know why spring security is not ignoring `Authorization` header for non secure endpoints.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55425391/2243324

Comment: Above might be duplicate of the problem , but solution will be different  as i am looking for solution in spring webflux

Comment: What do you mean with invalid `Authorization`? Invalid key? or invalid value?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `httpBasic()` method, Spring Security configure an `AuthenticationWebFilter` with a default anyExchange matcher, which means that every request that comes to your spring application is going to go through this filter. Also, `AuthenticationWebFilter` has precedence over `AuthorizationWebFilter` (see [Spring Security source code to know the order](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/SecurityWebFiltersOrder.java)).

In some point the request reach this method (see [Spring Security source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter.java)):

```
@Override
@Deprecated
public Mono<Authentication> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

    String authorization = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (!StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(authorization, "basic ")) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    String credentials = authorization.length() <= BASIC.length() ?
            "" : authorization.substring(BASIC.length(), authorization.length());
    byte[] decodedCredentials = base64Decode(credentials);
    String decodedAuthz = new String(decodedCredentials);
    String[] userParts = decodedAuthz.split(":", 2);

    if (userParts.length != 2) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    String username = userParts[0];
    String password = userParts[1];

    return Mono.just(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
}
```

Depending on which invalid header do you send, the result of this method could be:

1. An empty mono, which means the chain continues (this explains your 2 case).
2. An exception, here `AuthenticationWebFilter` is going to execute the `ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler`, this explains your failure case (see [AuthenticationWebFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/authentication/AuthenticationWebFilter.java)):

   ```
   @Override
   public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
   return this.requiresAuthenticationMatcher.matches(exchange)
       .filter( matchResult -> matchResult.isMatch())
       .flatMap( matchResult -> this.authenticationConverter.convert(exchange))
       .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.empty()))
       .flatMap( token -> authenticate(exchange, chain, token))
       .onErrorResume(AuthenticationException.class, e -> this.authenticationFailureHandler
           .onAuthenticationFailure(new WebFilterExchange(exchange, chain), e));
   }
   ```

By default this handler is going to ask again for the http basic headers.

The easiest way to bypass this, is implementing your own `AuthenticationWebFilter`, this will allow you to change the behavior.