# How to make Spring ignores token in the endpoint for botframework

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, botframework

I have an issue related to OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter, My application is expecting incoming messages from Microsoft Teams bot framework (/api/messages).

It seams like the messages are filtered because it contains an invalid token, but this endpoint should be public as it is set in the configuration
(noSecurityAllowedUrlPatterns cointains the endpoint):

```
http.requestMatchers()
          .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers(noSecurityAllowedUrlPatterns.toArray(new String[0]))
          .permitAll()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated();
```

Here is the line in the filter that throws the exception:

```
Authentication authResult = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
```

This is the endpoint:

```
@PostMapping({"/messages"})
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Object>> incoming(
      @RequestBody Activity activity,
      @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", defaultValue = "") String authHeader) {
...
}
```

How can I successfully set the configuration to avoid the oauth in this endpoint, or how I can I add the incoming token in a valid one list (somehow)?.
Maybe something wrong in the filter list order but

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding 'Authorization' header causes Spring Security to secure a permitted endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398826/adding-authorization-header-causes-spring-security-to-secure-a-permitted-endpo)

Answer (score 0):

IMO your HttpSecurity configuration does not look correct. If the endpoint that should be publicly available is `/api/messages` and all other endpoints should be secured, then you should change the configuration as follows:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/messages")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated();
```

IIRC this way you define filters that are applied from top to bottom. Means if the requests hits your backend and the first part of the configuration matches the request the second part is not relevant anymore. On the other side, if a request hits your backend that does not match the first part, the second part will be checked and so on.

This guide explains the general behavior: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture

Let me know if the code works (the snippet is created from memory). :)